# strategy for merging maintenance releases

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

My team (10 people) maintain a single codebase using SVN, and we're doing development of the next major version on the trunk while we fix bugs in the latest released version in a branch.

At the moment our strategy is that when we make a fix in the maintenance branch, we raise two tickets, one to fix it in the branch and one to fix it in the trunk. We then test the fix in both places.

Since we almost never want to make a fix in the maintenance branch which doesn't go through into the trunk, an easier way would be to periodically merge all changes from the branch into the trunk without specifically tracking or testing the individual fixes. Then it doesn't matter when or how often we merge as long as it's done before the new version is released.

We don't have any significant amount of automated test coverage (although the code is C# so at least it's compiled and strongly typed).

So my questions are, is the more rigorous method generally agreed to be the best practice or is it over-pedantic? are people using the "lazier" method effectively? Is there an alternative I haven't considered? If I was using git would this make the whole thing easier?

Comment: The last line is too opinion based!  I have done this in SVN via all fixes being made in the trunk, and daily merges to the branch.  Merging is not scary if you do it often.  Everyone has to mark changes that are relevant to the branch.

Comment: Thanks. If you're talking about merging from trunk to branch I guess this is feature branches which is not quite the same thing. But I think the point about merging more often is definitely something I will take on board. At the moment I'm sitting here with 130 changes to merge and 30 conflicts and wishing I hadn't let it go this far.

Comment: Merge them in small chunks, in chronological order, earliest first.  Check which files are affected for each change, so that you can spot potential conflicts in advance, and merge/check them in them separately.  For genuine conflicts, be ruthless about getting developers to check that your manual merges are correct.

Comment: It is a maintenance branch.  Not all changes on the trunk are relevant, which is why you need to get devs to mark if it should be merged or not.

Comment: does anyone else raise a separate bug-tracking ticket and re-test the change in the trunk once it's merged? that's something I'd be keen to avoid but since we don't have automated testing, I am erring on the side of paranoia there

Comment: To be honest, as a dev, I usually just test in one stream, unless I have a particular reason to think that the results could be different elsewhere. But yes, our bugs are destined specifically for different dev streams, and can get tested officially more than once.

Comment: Why not use task-separation and "branch per task" workflow? bugfix is separate branch (branches from relese-branch) and have to be merged (full branch, not range as in your case) twice^ into parent and trunk& Tree and history will be more readable and understandable IMHO